# How to force the downstream project to be built only once in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I'm using jenkins declarative pipeline for building my projects. There are 3 projects: *A*, *B* and *C*. Project *A* is the immediate downstream of *B* and *C*. Each time that projects *B* or *C* get triggered (via commits in Subversion), they produce an artifact (an SNAPSHOT), which will be then used by project *A*. For performance reasons I'd like to force the project *A* to be built only once, when projects *B* and *C* are being built or when they are waiting in the queue.

How could I achieve that using the declaritive pipelines?

Here are my pipeline source codes:

**A**:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven "maven"
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh "mvn clean install"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**B**:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven "maven"
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh "mvn clean install"
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      build job: 'A', wait: false
    }
  }
}
```

**C**:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven "maven"
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh "mvn clean install"
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      build job: 'A', wait: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Project B & C gets triggered at the same time for a commit?

Comment: @vijay Yes, they get triggered at the same time. Even when they don't get triggered at the exact same time, this assumption still holds. Because these projects take a long time to complete.

Comment: Can you create another Upstream wrapper pipeline? It should call B and C in parallel stages and next stage should call A. Will that work?

Comment: @saurabh14292 I'm not sure, if I understood your suggestion correctly. Could you please provide a sample pipeline code?

Comment: yes... I agree with @saurabh14292. pipeline triggers both B and C parallely from a single stage. Next stage checks if either project B or C is a success and triggers project A for the same commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way how jenkins deals with this Problem, and that is the use of `quietPriod(<time-to-wait-in-seconds>)`. So the Pipeline **A** would look like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven "maven"
  }
  options {
    quietPeriod(30)
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh "mvn clean install"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example if Project **B** triggers the downstream project **A**, **A** would not immediately start to build, but rather it waits for 30 seconds and then starts to build. If in this 30 seconds period the Project **C** (or again the project **B**) starts and triggers project **A**, **A** would only be built once.
I found [this post](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2010/08/11/quiet-period-feature/#:%7E:text=The%20queue%20portion%20of%20the,resets%20to%20its%20initial%20value.) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, posting basic code snippet of wrapper pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Trigger'){
            // Initial trigger if needed
        }
        stage('Build B and C'){
            parallel BuildB: {
                when{
                    // Condition to evaluate
                }
                steps {
                    // Trigger pipeline B
                }
            },
            BuildC: {
                when{
                    // Condition to evaluate
                }
                steps {
                    // // Trigger pipeline C
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build A'){
            // Trigger pipeline A
        }
    }
}
```

This wrapper pipeline will execute B and C in parallel, and only upon completion of both, will trigger A.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits my needs. This pipeline triggers both B AND C and they will execute in parallel, right? But I don't want B and C to get triggered always simultaneously. Maybe there is a change only in project B but nothing has changed in Project C or vice versa. In this case I don't want the unchanged project get triggered. How could achieve such a thing?

Comment: You can further update above script by adding "when" clause in BuildB and BuildC. Even though they are designed to execute in parallel, if "when" clause is not satisfied, you can skip the execution. In that way, you can skip either of the B and C or execute both in parallel.

Comment: Edited above pipeline with "When" clause. Refer this : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Comment: It is a good solution. I have this strong requirement, that whenever an instance of B or C is being built or is waiting in the queue, Pipeline A should not be triggered. But according to your suggestion, there exists the possibility, that 2 or more instances of the wrapper pipeline are being built or are waiting in the queue. Each of which at the end trigger pipeline A. How could one avoid such a thing?

Comment: pipeline A to have restriction/configuration of "not to execute multiple instances in parallel" , will this work?

Comment: They get serialized when not executed concurrently. Say Pipeline A has 2 instances a1 and a2. When they could not be executed concurrently, one of them, say a2, waits in the queue until a1 finishes, and then gets executed. What i want is that only one instance, e.g. a1 to be executed.

Comment: Further more consider an instance of A is waiting until all of the upstream projects finish they work. In the mean time the upstream projects (could be all of them or only one of them) get triggered again. The instance of project A should be still waiting until these new jobs get done and only if there are no upstream project being executed, then it could start working and be build ONLY one time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214882/discussion-between-saurabh14292-and-sina-barghidarian).